# Running selenium webdriver test error using phantomjs with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I was running a selenium test with chrome driver just fine.

And i decided to change it to phantomjs, but I´m getting some error.

First i open the webpage i need:

```
driver.get("https://webp.caixa.gov.br/urbanizacao/siurbn/acompanhamento/ac_publico/sistema/asp/ptei_filtro_inicial.asp");
```

And in this line :

```
driver.findElement(By.name("txtNr_Contrato_Plano_Trab")).sendKeys(strContratoNumero.substring(0, 9));
```

i get this error:

[ERROR - 2014-10-13T12:41:25.633Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found : GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1413204085616.

and this same line works with chrome and firefox.

It is probably not finding the element right?

When i use phantomjs, do I need to change, add or delete something? I just changed this part:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: @PhilPeace yes i did

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same annoying problem. How did you fix it?

Comment: the browser was not even opening. so of course the element not found. try this System.out.println(driver.getPageSource()); to guide you @PhilPeace

Comment: @BrunoSousa It would be nice to see the answer as I am getting the same issue with scrolling and chrome. Plus it gets you points and "points mean prizes".

Comment: Even i am facing the same issue.. It works fine with chromeDriver but fails with phantomJsDriver.. could you please post the solution